# How can i change a php variable with a button

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, button

I want to change my date variable `$date='date DESC'` with one button to `$date='ASC'`. 
I solved it with a submit button, but I don`t want it that my page is loading again.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
  <button name='submit' value='0'>down</button>
  <button name='submit' value='1'>up</button>
  </form>
```

php code

```
if($_POST['submit']==0)      { $datum='date DESC'; }
else if($_POST['submit']==1) { $datum='date ASC'; 

}
```

Comment: If you don't want your page to reload again I think you have to use AJAX instead (AJAX calling PHP script). To me, the best solution would be to use jQuery using the $.ajax prototype OR $.post prototype; therefore, I think this is what you're looking for: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ . If you don't want to use AJAX, feel free to use javascript only and, once you have generated the page containing all what you need, hide and show divs according to a few buttons, but is it worth to do that when you can easily use AJAX? :)

Comment: Without reloading you need AJAX. PHP is serverside, once the page is fully loaded, every change requires a reload.

Comment: thanks...with a little bit i-net research i fixed my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use AJAX here if you want to load only a certain portion of the page or not submit it. Basically if you dont want to change the page.

Lets give some IDs to the buttons.

```
<button id="b1" onclick="send_data(this.value)" value='0'>down</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="send_data(this.value)" value='1'>up</button>
```

Now we'll create the ajax object

```
var ajaxObject;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  ajaxObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else 
{ // code for IE6, IE5
  ajaxObject = new activeXObject("MICROSOFT.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Now to create the function to send the data to the server. This will take the data and send it to your PHP page as GET entries.

```
function send_data(value)
{
ajaxObject.open("GET","phppage.php?submit=" . value . ,true);
ajaxObject.send();
}
```

Your php code should work just fine on the Backend.

This was done using ID's for two separate id (i.e two separate buttons. But the same thing can be accomplished by using forms and some slight modifications.

Another trival solution would be to simply SUBMIT and handle the process after that in a new page (Blank window, New window, etc). :)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is interpreted on the server side, but your button click is a client action. You **need** to transmit the information to the server (you want to change a PHP variable value), and this "transmission" is called an *HTTP request*, which is what you call "loading the page again". You can use Ajax to make a asynchronous request, yet, it has to happen.

By the way, if you want to order another HTML element (maybe your dates are in a `<select>` element ?), you should sort it using Javascript, not PHP.